# UTM tracking codes in Firebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-analytics, utm

How to make that **Firebase** understand and track installation of apps (iOS and Android) with UTM tracking links (for example I want to track installs of apps from my site from footer link)? In GA it works perfect.

In Firebase I din't find any documentations on it (in app only **Firebase SDK** without Google Analytics).

[Utm link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yamiyami.ozdigital.yamiyami&referrer=utm_source%3Dyamiyamiru%26utm_medium%3Dflat%26utm_campaign%3Dfooter)

Comment: Do you mean campaign tracking? Android and iOS Analytics SDK can automatically extract those UTM params and create campaign events. Let me know if you meant something else.

Comment: I'm also not able to see campaign information in Firebase Analytics - Attribution - first_open. I can only see direct/none, whereas on GA I can see other campaigns. I'm using a custom INSTALL_REFERRER receiver and calling CampaignTrackingReceiver.onReceive.

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamic link with UTMs in Firebase console[image: Firebase Dynamic Links]

Answer (score 0):

The info is in **Conversion** tab in the Firebase dashboard.

What you may want to do is to apply the filter with "**first_open**" which is the event name.

[image]